# KineticJS not able to fill Polygon with Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

After updating KineticJS from v4.0.5 to v4.3.1, I can no longer fill a Polygon with an Image using this method:

```
polygon.setFill({
    image: imageObj
});
```

I end up with a black background. Is there another way around this?

**Attempt:** I tried `poly.setFillPattern(image)`

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eeSSN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove "fill" config in  Kinetic.Polygon.
- You created thingImage but never used it.
- You can use "setFillPatternImage"
- You have to call stage.draw inside iamge.onload

Code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
   container: 'canvas',
   width: 600,
   height: 600
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
// Outline
var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [0, 0, 400, 0, 400, 400, 0, 400],
    //fill: 'red',
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    name: 'poly',
    draggable: false
});
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
imageObj.onload = function() {
    poly.setFillPatternImage(imageObj);
    stage.draw();
}

layer.add(poly);
stage.add(layer);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/eeSSN/1/